# Evaluate Double integral of a complicated exponential function

Tags: calculus

Could someone point out how to evaluate this Double integral?

$\int^{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}_0 \int^a_0 \dfrac{xe^y}{(y-a)^2} dxdy$

Thanks!!

Comment: We certainly have $$\int_0^a \frac{e^y}{(y-a)^2}dy = e^{a}\int_{-a}^0 \frac{e^u}{u^2}du$$ for $u = y-a$ This looks possible to evaluate using the product rule.

Comment: How can $x$ be in the bound for the outer integral but be the variable of integration for the inner integral?